# Call +(void)method from -(IBAction)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

First of all, sorry if the title is misleading. This is literally my first ever creation with Xcode, so I may be a bit off with what everything is called and such.

So, I have a class with a few `IBAction`'s, something like this:

```
// AppController.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject {

}

+ (void)addItem;

- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

And:

```
// AppController.m

#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController

+ (void)addItem {
    NSLog("Action");
}

- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {
    [[self class] addItem];
}
```

When I run the app and click the button that fires the `IBAction`, the app hangs and the Xcode-window becomes selected, with a green "breakpoint" on the line `NSLog(...)`.

I have no idea what this reaction is called, nor what I am supposed to do about it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSLog("Action");
```

The first argument of `NSLog()` must be an `NSString`, not a C string (`char *`). You missed the `@` character:

```
NSLog(@"Action");
```

is the correct approach.

Edit: if it's just a typo, and after fixing it, the problem still persists: then you most likely set a breakpoint on that particular line. Delete or disable the breakpoint to enable the program to continue.

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiled.

Comment: Woops, I'm sorry, but this is only a typo in this question. I simply added the `NSLog` there instead of the actual code I have. No matter what code is in there, it always results in the same "breakpoint" on that first line of the method.

Comment: @trojanfoe pointer, pointer, it issues a warning, but it's generally not an error...

Comment: Okay, so your comment made me try what I should've tried already. I searched for the breakpoints and then simply removed a breakpoint there. I don't know why I had one, nor what it does, but the problem is now solved. Thank you.

Comment: @MarttiLaine: A breakpoint causes the debugger to break—meaning interrupt—execution when the program reaches that point. It's how you tell the debugger “OK, when you get to here, stop there and let me try something”.